# How to get the cell position in spreadsheet in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet

Is there any way to get the position(Co-ordinates) of spreadsheet cell in ruby on rails using gem like roo, spreadsheet etc. ?

Suppose I have value "TOTAL" in Cth column and 2nd row. How to get this position using ruby on rails?

Any hints?

Comment: Can you post the code you write so far??

Answer (score 1):

```
#http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html

require 'spreadsheet'
book = Spreadsheet.open 'sample.xls'
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
sheet1.each_with_index do |row, index|
  for column in 0..(row.length-1)
    puts "Row:- #{index}, Column: #{column}, Value: #{row[column]}" 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from roo official tutorials http://roo.rubyforge.org/
Hope it would help

```
HOURLY_RATE = 123.45

oo = Openoffice.new("simple_spreadsheet.ods")
oo.default_sheet = oo.sheets.first

4.upto(12) do |line|
    date       = oo.cell(line,'A')
    start_time = oo.cell(line,'B')
    end_time   = oo.cell(line,'C')
    pause      = oo.cell(line,'D')
    sum        = (end_time - start_time) - pause
    comment    = oo.cell(line,'F')
    amount     = sum * HOURLY_RATE
    if date
     puts "#{date}\t#{sum}\t#{amount}\t#{comment}"
 end
end
```